# S trap 40ft from ptrap?

Tags: plumbing

2" kitchen drain goes down into crawlspace, 90s, then goes 40ft into a 3x2y 5ft away from where the 4" main comes under the foundation, in that 40ft it has 2ft of drop(way too much?), it bowes up on the 90 side of the beam and bowed down making back fall on the 3x2 wye side of the beam which cracked the top of the pipe at the wye and the straps don't work so I'll need to adjust those.  My question is, if I raise the pipe and give it 1/4 of fall will puting a 90 at the end & angle down to the 3x2 wye create an S trap? I plan to maybe just replace the wye and adjust the inlet up but I'd still have a good 1"-2" of fall when I only want 1/4 at most right?

Comment: Or might 45 further up & angle down to the 3x2 wye but just wondering if thad create s trap & suck water out of ptrap if it's angled too much making the drop after the 45 or 90 a good 1"or 2" of drop into the 3x2wye.  If 2" of drop isn't too much I can just replace the 3x2 & turn it up ...?

Comment: 1/4" per foot is the minimum , it's not really a trap with that much separation it is best to reduce the number of fittings and increase the slope or when the system plugs you will find getting a snake down there to clean it out may be impossible.